# Pusher on angular 5?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5, pusher, pusher-js

Here is the js code to add pusher in native html

```
<head>
<title>Pusher Test</title>
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.1/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script>

// Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

var pusher = new Pusher('MY_PUSHER_KEY', {
  cluster: 'MY_CLUSTER',
  encrypted: true
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
  alert(data.message);
});
```

how i can add js script above to one of my angular component, so they can subscribe to that channel?
thanks a lot for those who answer this, really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In angular 4 or 5 or above you will use the JavaScript version of Pusher and you will install it inside your project, here is a simple example for that : 
1- Install Pusher in your angular project :

```
npm install --save pusher-js
```

2- Open .angular-cli.json file and add this to ("scripts"):

```
"scripts": ["../node_modules/pusher-js/dist/web/pusher.min.js"]
```

3- You should make an http request to your server to be able to make this request , then we will use a service for that so you should generate a service with angular cli or make it with the way you prefer:

```
 ng g s my-service
```

- Note :
   
       - Don't Forget to register this service in app.module.ts , also for HttpClientModule or HttpModule as we will use one of them in out service

5- In my-service.service.ts:
   - after you import the httpClient , write this statement to begin using puhser,

```
declare const Pusher: any;
```

6- In the Constructor of My Service :

```
   this.pusher = new Pusher('YOUR_PUSHER_KEY', {
      cluster: 'YOUR_PUSHER_CLUSTER',
      encrypted: true
    });
    this.channel = this.pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
```

7- After that make a function that will make the post request to your server to make the trigger for your event.
8-After you finish the service, go to the component that you want to work in, register your service first in its constructor and then bind to the channel to what your event which will be (my-event) in your example:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.channel.bind('my-event', data => {
      this.message = data.message;
    });
  }
```

Now you make a simple real time app in your Angular 5 Project!